# C# Asp.Net Application Creating Duplicate SQL Records After Timeout

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, duplicates

I hope that my question is not flagged for being too vague, but I have been grasping at straws for some time now...

I have a simple ASP.Net application that allows users to add, modify, or delete customer records.  About once a week, I get a user report that "I modified a record, hit save, and got an error that the SQL connection timed out.  When I tried to go back into the record, I found that there was a duplicate record."

I can confirm the result - I am getting duplicate records that are identical except for an auto-incremented ID field.  These duplicates are easy enough to clean up, but I cannot figure out what is causing this.  The method that seems to trigger the duplicates is straightforward - it uses a SqlConnection and a SqlCommand with CommandText like:

```
"UPDATE Accounts SET Param1 = @Param1, Param2 = @Param2... WHERE CustomerNumber like '" + (string)Session["CustomerNumber"] + "';"
```

SQL Error or otherwise, this shouldn't cause a duplicate as far as I know.  I have done a "Find All -> Entire Solution" looking for "INSERT INTO Accounts" and find only one place where an Account record is created.  That is on a different page, and sets the Customer Number to a random value, which is not consistent behavior with the duplicates I am getting.

I have also double checked the database for Triggers or Stored Procedures - there are none.

I don't even know what part of my code to post to look for a solution... does anybody have any ideas of additional debugging procedures to try or has anyone else experienced this?  I am using an Azure Web App and and Azure SQL Database, but I think this bug existed when I was operating in IIS and SQL Server 2008 also, prior to migrating to Azure.  Thank you in advance for any suggestions!

Comment: Is the user double-clicking the submit button?

Comment: How is the "auto-incremented ID field." generated ? Is it an identity column ?

Comment: Why do use "like" and not "=" in your update query? Is it possible that in your original query you use "%" and so if your customer number is 100 this update will update all customers with ids that contain the string '100'?

Comment: @David - I considered the same thing, and it is possible, but I still don't see how this would trigger a new record...  I am not handling a double-click with a different method, but I'm not doing anything to filter them out either.

Comment: @user957902 - yes, it's an identity column.

Comment: @ElementalPete: `"but I still don't see how this would trigger a new record"` - Well, if clicking once creates a record, then clicking twice would create two records, wouldn't it?

Comment: @bumpy - I don't remember the reason I am doing that, but it is set to the value of the session variable Customer Number, which by definition only has letters and numbers.  This was my first c# project, created a couple of years ago, and I am refactoring based on experience as I go.  I will try changing this to an = to see if that stops the issue.  Good feedback :)

Comment: @David - Yes, but the user is updating a record when the bug occurs, not creating one.  In the only spot in the program where records are created, it simply assigns it a new (unique) customer number, and opens up an edit window prompting for additional info. When the duplicates are being created, they have all of the info filled out and identical to the existing record that was being edited.  Most of these records are pretty old, actually.

Comment: I would suggest running the SQL Query Profiler on the applications SQL Server. There must be an insert happening somewhere (perhaps an exception handler ?) . The only way you are going to get a new identity value is to insert. The other option is that you are updating the identity column value, but that would require 2 updates.

Comment: Any chance there's a trigger on the table being updated?

Comment: @Kidiskidvogingogin - No, I double-checked the database for triggers and found none.  I typically don't use any triggers.  This is an old issue - I don't think that I ever figured out what was going on, but I haven't gotten any complaints about it in a long time.  Maybe it was my use of "like" instead of "=" causing it to update 2 records at the same time?  I don't think so, though, because I seem to recall that the duplicate was always the newest record (which would be consistent with "insert" behavior.)